# How to split an IP Address string in DB2 SQL (for converting to IP Number)?

Tags: sql, string, db2, ip-address

How can you convert a IP address string into an IP Address number (useful for IP country detection) in DB2 SQL?

Converting to the number is easy, you do something like:

```
16777216 * v + 65536 * x + 256 * y + z
```

where the IP is in the form `v.x.y.z`. Plenty of examples, source for this [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csv).

So, the problem becomes, how to parse the IP address string to pull out the components.

In Transact-SQL you can use `PARSENAME` to do this easily, described [here](http://www.firstbigstep.net/content/Convert_IP_Address_to_IP_Number_SQL.aspx).

How can you do the equivalent in DB2 SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not found anything cleaner and simpler than this, but the following SQL will do the job.

```
SELECT
    LO.IPAddress
    16777216 * CAST(LEFT(LO.IPAddress, LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1)-1) AS BIGINT)
    +  65536 * CAST(SUBSTR(LO.IPAddress, LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1) + 1, LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress,LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1) +1) - LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1) - 1) AS BIGINT)
    +    256 * CAST(SUBSTR(LO.IPAddress, LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress,LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1) +1) + 1, LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress,LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1) +1) +1) - LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress,LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1) +1) - 1) AS BIGINT) 
    +          CAST(RIGHT(LO.IPAddress, LENGTH(LO.IPAddress) - LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress,LOCATE('.', LO.IPAddress, 1) +1) +1)) AS BIGINT)
    AS IPNumber

FROM Login LO
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you. Now if someone would just embed AWK inside SQL, we wouldn't need crazy code like this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

select IP,(CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(IP,1)) + CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(IP,2)) * 256 + CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(IP,3)) * 65536 +
CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(IP,4)) * 16777216) from IPTable

Comment: As per the question, `PARSENAME` isn't available in DB2 (or certainly not at the time of writing...)